# How to "reverse" string that acts as a date time?

Tags: javascript, mysql, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on a Vue project and I have a textfield that takes "date-time" to string variable like this **DD-MM-YYYY**.

I want to convert it to MySQL format **(YYYY-MM-DD)**

Example input: **24-05-2022** 
Example output: **2022-05-24**

So since

```
dateInput: '24-05-2022'
dateInput.split("").reverse().join("")
```

Would change the `dateInput` value to:

```
2202-50-42
```

I'm wondering **how to reverse the string without affecting numbers next to eachother?**

**EDIT** -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Forgot to mention I'm using **NuxtJs** with Vue so the syntax is a little different.

**Works now with:** 
 
Data

```
dateInput: '24-05-2022',
array: [],
newDate: ''
```

Methods

```
reverseDate () {
    this.array = this.dateInput.split('-')
    this.newDate = this.array[2] + '-' + this.array[1] + '-' + this.array[0]
}
```

Created

```
this.reverseDate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
let dateInput = '24-05-2022';
let array = dateInput.split("-");
let newDate = `${array[2]}-${array[1]}-${array[0]}`;

console.log(newDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first try was close to be correct, you just missed including the '-'.
This code would also work:

```js
let dateInput = '24-05-2022';
let reversed = dateInput.split('-').reverse().join('-');
console.log(reversed) // outputs: 2022-05-24
```

And if you would need a Date object, `new Date(reversed)` works like a charm.